# Fortran source code file setup and column rules: SWAN

Tags: fortran

Im tring to understand sourceforge swan wave model fortran source code. One point of confusion is the different files in the source code folder (.edt,.ftn,.ftn90,.inc,.lst,.nml,.pl,.eps,.bat), now I know what sort most of these files are but the naming convention is a little boggling.

I look at swanmain.ftn and I can't understand: Is the compiler just read this file in order because there seems to be no initialization of SWMAIN like (eg "program SWMAIN") it just starts with IMLICIT NONE?? And it just has END then next line is a bunch of USE statements?? The only formal declaration of the start of SWMAIN is in a comment.

Another question i have is it seams that in columns 75:end there is a number eg 40.30 seams like a version number where that line was added or edited, yet there is no ! or c to initialize comment so are lines past 75 just assumed to be unused ( I know fortran has line format of those old punch cards but I thought it ended at column 80)?

Where should I start as far as understanding how this program is set out ie which file will give me the most insite into what all the other files do.. Should I understand makefile format?

Sorry for all the noob questions as I basically never studied programming just kinda learn while doing. Ive written a few programs in Java and C++ but mostly MATLAB.

Thanks

Comment: You are right about punch cards --used up to about FORTRAN IV. Columns 73 to 80 are ignored by the compiler in standard fixed-form source form (up to Fortran 77).  They could be used for a line number, so that if you dropped your card deck it could be mechanically sorted.  This was improved long ago... Fortran >=90 uses free-form source form.

Comment: based on a quick look the code is fixed format but full of "comments" using an `!` in column 1, which is not a standard fortran fixed format comment convention. That and the odd "ftn" extension tells me this goes through a preprocessor.  And oh my those numbers on the right are *ugly*

Comment: before someone calls me on it the `!` is recognized by modern compilers in fixed format..never mind..

Comment: This wave model is widely used and publicly modified extensively, Im pretty sure that the numbers on the right are version numbers. I don't expect neat code when its written by many random parties whom im assuming are coastal engineers and not programers. It's anything but user friendly. But thats the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Most of the sources should be obvious: `ftn` and `ftn90` are Fortran sources, `nml` is a [Namelist](http://www.sdsc.edu/~tkaiser/f90.html#Namelist) file, `pl` is a Perl script, `eps` is a figure, `bat` is a [Windows Batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), `inc` is an "include" file (not language specific) and "lst" appears to be a list (not sure the relevance).
- The code appear to be written primarily in FORTRAN 77 standard. As such, anything past line 72 (not 80) is truncated as a comment (gfortran will even warn you that it's doing so if you have `-Wall` enabled).
- Fortran technically does not require a `PROGRAM <name>` declaration. Really the only thing *required* in a Fortran code is `END` to end it.

If you are trying to figure the program out, I would suggest:

1. Read the documentation at least twice.
2. Read relevant publications from the code (specifically the initial announcement of the code)
3. Start by looking at the main program and seeing where the calls go (this is probably a very slow and bad way to do it, since it looks to be a fairly long code)